# How to make website stop scrolling down in certain point?

Tags: html, css, scroll, responsive-design

this is my code: 
[Link to Codepen](https://codepen.io/firefun365/pen/YzKorQZ)

How do I make the website stop scrolling down where the content actually ends?

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

in body element, it won't work because it will not give me scroll the page at all. but I need to scroll it down where my content ends.
How can I do it or prevent it in the most simple way except using js or bootstrap?

The problem happening because every new element goes lower and lower.

Thank you for help !

Comment: Hi welcome to SO! Your issues become more apparent visually if you just add `* { outline: red 1px dashed }` to add a visual guide that displays a need for you to improve understanding of the [CSS Box Model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/The_box_model) and the proper usage of the `position` attribute understanding the differences between `static`, `relative`, and `absolute` and how they effect [DOM Flow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Normal_Flow). Making the question unfortunately very broad.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because many elements has `position:relative`. Position relative saves place where element should be rendered by default.

You need change html structure and css.

Example: [codepen](https://codepen.io/alexandr-ryazantsev/pen/XWWWryG)